# Creating artificial data out of data that only contains sentences

Tags: python

I am trying to create artificial data. However my current data only contains sentences.

Two example rows that I have are the following:

> Your order is on its way with tracking {imaginary tracking code}. Visit {imaginary random link} for more information.

> The package has been shipped out with tracking {imaginary tracking code}. Visit {imaginary random link} for more information.

Now what I want to do is basically take these sentences and create thousands of them but with randomized tracking codes. I thought about splitting the sentences at two at the tracking code but couldn't figure out a way to split them at the specific tracking code. Like most tracking codes they contains numbers but also sometimes letters(usually at the front).

My current method which is bad would be to split the sentence into words. then check each word if it contains numbers. If it does contain a number that is the tracking code and now I have my way of creating artificial version of that sentence by taking everything before the tracking code inserting my artificial tracking code and everything after the tracking code. Repeating this for every row in the dataset and then randomizing the dataset.

So my question is, is there a more optimal way?

Comment: Regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use regex to identify the codes to replace with random codes.
This example is deliberately simplified, I have used static codes and not randomly generated one and the regex pattern needs to be defined and refined.

```
import re 
sentences = ('Your order is on its way with tracking 1234567890. Visit 98765432 for more information.',
'The package has been shipped out with tracking 1245789865. Visit 65659865 for more information.')

code1='9999999999'
code2='11111111'

for x in sentences:
  y = re.findall(r'(\D*)\d+(\D*)\d+(\D*)' ,x)
  if y[0][2]:
    z = y[0][0] + code1 + y[0][1] + code2 + y[0][2]
    print(z)
```

output

```
Your order is on its way with tracking 9999999999. Visit 11111111 for more information.
The package has been shipped out with tracking 9999999999. Visit 11111111 for more information.
```